# Data to be read by humans in Python (large data sets)

Tags: python

If I want to write out large data sets without displaying it on the screen then I have to use some built-in functions, as well as use all kind of separators and labels so I can write them out directly to a file.

However, I was having such a hard time understanding of all little details in a tutorial code so I was wondering if you could explain this small piece of code to me using probably a plain language and line-by-line then that would be great. I would like to use this code as an example and refer to it in the future as needed. What all those letters and signs, such as "N", "t", "n", "d", and "---", as well as "----" and "pow" mean in the code?

Here is the code:

```
#print_write.py
my_file = open('power.txt', 'w')
print ("N\t\t2**N\t\t3**N")
print ("---\t\t----\t\t----")
my_file.write("N\t\t2**N\t\t3**N\n")
my_file.write("---\t\t----\t\t----\n")
for N in range(11):
    print("{:d}\t\t{:d}\t\t{:d}".format(N, pow(2, N), pow(3, N)))
    my_file.write("{:d}\t\t{:d}\t\t{:d}\n".format(N, pow(2, N), pow(3, N)))
my_file.close()
```

Comment: `\t\t` is adding two tabs of space between items, so for `print ("N\t\t2**N\t\t3**N")` you can see the headers are separated on the very first line of the printout. `\n` is for newlines, to stack data in columns. `print("{:d}\t\t{:d}\t\t{:d}".format(N, pow(2, N), pow(3, N)))` notice that there are as many `{:d}` as there are items in `format(1, 2, 3)` - the values are being placed into the string in the order they are supplied to `format` and in the positions marked by `{:d}`. The best way is to go through line-by-line for each print statement and correlate with the printed output.

Comment: @roganjosh: I think that comment deserves to be an answer.  Post as such so OP can accept it and get the question archived?

Comment: @Prune I didn't go the whole way and left it open-ended with enough to try make sense of the output. Is that acceptable to leave the rest as an exercise?

Comment: Yes, I know.  You cut through the most confusing part, and left a small enough chunk.  If OP needs follow-up after due diligence, an answer is a better place to hang that interaction.

Comment: @roganjosh - thank you for your answer! I will definitely use your explanation as a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to approach this is probably to go through the `print` statements line-by-line and correlate the code with what you see actually printed out. In this case, the printout is:

```
N               2**N            3**N
---             ----            ----
0               1               1
1               2               3
2               4               9
3               8               27
4               16              81
5               32              243
6               64              729
7               128             2187
8               256             6561
9               512             19683
10              1024            59049
```

Some parts of this I think you should research yourself, e.g. `format` and `pow` as you need to get familiar with googling your way through this stuff. However, some other parts are cluttered so I agree it's not so simple. I'll remove a few of them to hopefully make it a bit clearer:

- `\t\t` is giving two tabs of space between items. You can see this in the header by correlating `print ("N\t\t2**N\t\t3**N")` with the very first line of the printout.
- Understanding that line also immediately clarifies the next line for the meaning of `---` as code (... it has none, it's a string).
- `\n` is a newline character which is helping to give the printouts in columns rather than in a single row.
- In the case of `print("{:d}\t\t{:d}\t\t{:d}".format(N, pow(2, N), pow(3, N)))` notice how there are as many `{:d}` as there are values in `.format(x, y, z)`. The values supplied to `format` are being used to populate the string, in order, at the positions of the `{:d}` placeholders.
- Note that `print` statements will automatically add a newline character at the end of each line, but `write` will not. So in this case, if you want to mirror each print statement as a single line in a written file, you have to add `\n` to the end of whatever the printed string was e.g. 
  `print("{:d}\t\t{:d}\t\t{:d}".format(N, pow(2, N), pow(3, N)))` 
  had to become 
  `my_file.write("{:d}\t\t{:d}\t\t{:d}\n".format(N, pow(2, N), pow(3, N)))` 
   with the extra `\n` just before the `.format` part.